# Regex to match digits of specific length

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to match a 15 digit number (as part of a larger regex string). Right now, I have

```
\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d
```

but I feel like there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: to get an idea, take a look at https://gist.github.com/SHi-ON/b2ae4100f50b2e2d96ff8277632cc325

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If your regex language is Perl-compatible: `\d{15}`.

It is difficult to say how handle the edges (so you don't accidentally grab extra digits) without knowing the outer context in which this snippet will be used. The definitive context-independent solution is this:

```
(?<!\d)\d{15}(?!\d)
```

You can put this in the middle of any regex and it will match (and only match) a sequence of exactly 15 digits. It is, however, quite awkward, and usually unnecessary. A simpler version that assumes non-alphanumeric boundaries (e.g., whitespace around the digits) is this:

```
\b\d{15}\b
```

But it won't work if the letters immediately precede or followed the sequence.

Comment: Using built in python regex library.

Comment: Your answer is the best because it allows both matching and extracting x-digit numbers from a longer string too.

Answer (score 71):

You can generally do ranges as follows:

```
\d{4,7}
```

which means a minimum of 4 and maximum of 7 digits. For your particular case, you can use the one-argument variant, `\d{15}`.

Both of these forms are supported in [Python's regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) - look for the text `{m,n}` at that link.

And keep in mind that `\d{15}` will match fifteen digits anywhere in the line, including a 400-digit number. If you want to ensure it only has the fifteen, you use something like:

```
^\d{15}$
```

which uses the start and end anchors, or

```
^\D*\d{15}\D*$
```

which allows arbitrary non-digits on either side.

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem - i forgot to anchor my tests.

Comment: ... and keep in mind that `$` matches a newline; use `\Z` instead.

Comment: This allows matching but doesn't allow extracting x digits numbers from a longer string too.

Answer (score -4):

There, are two ways i have, to limit numbers.

using **len**,

```
num = 1234
len(str(num)) <= 4
```

This output will be True / False.

using **regular expression**,

```
import re
num = 12324
re.match(r'(?:(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d))', str(num))
```

The output will be regular expression object or None.