# Regex to match a specific group of digits of certain length?

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this: [Regex to match digits of specific length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824942/regex-to-match-digits-of-specific-length) but it talks about Python. I am wanting to be able to get a group of random numbers of specific length. So if I have `167691#15316243` it will match `15316243`. I am not sure how to implement this. right now I have `new RegExp('[0-9]+', "g");` which matches a group of numbers fine, but now I realized I will have some times when I have more than one group and I only want the group of eight numbers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify the length of a matching set using {}.

For example: `[0-9]{8}`

Which will match any numbers from 0 to 9 with a specific length of 8 characters.

You can also specify a min/max range instead of forcing a specific legnth. So if you wanted a min of 4 and a max of 8 the example would change to: `[0-9]{4,8}`

Comment: You almost certainly want boundaries.

Answer (score 29):

```
[0-9]+ - Matches one or more numbers
[0-9]{8} - Matches exactly 8 numbers.
[0-9]{8,10} - Matches between 8 and 10 numbers.
[0-9]{8,} - Matches 8 or more numbers.
[0-9]* - Matches zero or more numbers.
[0-9]? - Matches zero or one number.
```

Comment: [0-9]{8,} - minimum length is 8

Comment: @ThoQLuong added, thanks! Was unable to accept the review due to reputation requirements.

Comment: Important note: do not add a space after coma in `{8,10}`. It should be exactly `{8,10}` not `{8, 10}`

Answer (score 4):

Simply put the repetition amount in curly braces:

```
"167691#15316243".match(/\d{8}/g);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r5vd/

---

I'd suggest you read [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (scroll down to the section on Limiting Repetition).

Here's a quote:

> Modern regex flavors [...] have an additional repetition operator that allows you to specify how many times a token can be repeated. The syntax is `{min,max}`, where `min` is a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and `max` is an integer equal to or greater than `min` indicating the maximum number of matches. If the comma is present but `max` is omitted, the maximum number of matches is infinite. So `{0,}` is the same as `*`, and `{1,}` is the same as `+`.
>   Omitting both the comma and max tells the engine to repeat the token exactly `min` times.