# How to write this number detecting regexp in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, perl

This is how it looks like in Perl-compatible regexp (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824952/377920):

```
(?:(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?!\d))
```

However, apparently Javascript lacks some regexp features so this doesn't work.

I'm trying to match 1-3 long connected digits that can have non-white characters on both ends.

Such as "Road 12A55, 10020" would match 12 and 55.

Comment: Not really the solution you asked for, but the clean way to test if a string is a number in Javascript is to use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/JavaScript_Guide/Fonctions_pr%C3%A9d%C3%A9finies/La_fonction_isNaN)

Comment: What is the pattern you're trying to match?

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Why not just grab all substrings of digits (via the simple regex `(\d+)`) and then see if the matched groups have a length between 1 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not support `look-behinds`, that is why your regex didn't work.

You can try out this alternative: -

```
/(?:^|\D)(\d{1,3})(?!\d)/
```

And get the `group 1`.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.

It looks like you are trying to detect a sequence of no more than 3 digits. Depending on what the surrounding context is, you may be able to use this instead:

```
/(?:^|\D)\d{1,3}(?:\D|$)/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite the expression without lookbehinds - just make sure to get group 1:

```
/(?:^|\D)(\d{1,3})(?!\d)/
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns 12 and 55:

```
var output = 'Road 12A55, 10020'.replace(/D+|\d{4,}/g, ' ').match(/\d+/g)

alert(output)
```