# How can I match a number that is at least 5-digits-long or more using RegEx?

Tags: regex

There are topics on Stack Overflow on how to [match a number of a certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824942/regex-to-match-digits-of-specific-length), but that's not what I'm trying to do.

I'd like to match a number that has 5-digits or more but not if it's followed or preceded by anything other than numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\d{5,}`, which matches 5 digits or more, then:

- If you want this number as a *word* use **`\b\d{5,}\b`**. `\b` matches word boundaries.
- If that’s a number on *its own line*, use **`^\d{5,}$`**. `^` matches the beginning of the line while `$` matches its end.

Here is [an example](http://regex101.com/r/gU0hE0/1).

Answer (score 3):

You may try this regex:

```
^\D*(?:\d\D*){5,}$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uR2yW2/1)**

or more simple:

```
^\d{5,}$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uR2yW2/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Use ^ for the start of string and $ for the end of string.

```
/^[\d]{5,}$/
```

So string of '12354' is true but string of '12345 foo' is false. Is it your question?

Comment: You can use `\d` instead of `[\d]`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for

```
/(?<=\d\s)\d{5,}(?=\s\d)/g
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  \d                       digits (0-9)
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
)                        end of look-behind
\d{5,}                   digits (0-9) (at least 5 times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
  \d                       digits (0-9)
)                        end of look-ahead
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kK8pV3/1)

Or something more complicated

```
/(?<=\d(?:\s))\d{5,}(?=\s(?:\d))/g
```