# How Do I Find a Specific Expression within a Dataframe Column?

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe with a column called "Description." I want to scan through all the text in this column, and identify those rows that have a description that contains a number that is at least 3 digits long.

Here's where I'm at:

```
import re 
df['StrDesc'] = df['Description'].str.split()
y=re.findall('[0-9]{3}',str(df['StrDesc'])
print(y)
```

I took my text column and converted it to a string. Do I need to then run a for loop to iterate through each row before using the final regex?

Am I going about this the best way?

My error is "unexpected EOF while parsing."

Comment: You're missing a parentheses at the end of your 3rd line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), `split` is not necessary :

```
y = df['Description'].str.findall('[0-9]{3}')
```

But with some testing [general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824952/2901002) is a bit complicated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['354 64 133 5867 4 te345',
                                  'rt34 3tyr 456',
                                  '23 gh346h rt 9404']})

print(df)
               Description
0  354 64 133 5867 4 te345
1            rt34 3tyr 456
2        23 gh346h rt 9404

y = df['Description'].str.findall('(?:(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d))')
print (y)
0    [354, 133, 345]
1              [456]
2              [346]
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Comment: Using panda's built-in str manipulations and regex is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @PMende - absolutely agree ;)

Comment: Thank you, all! I was thinking it was more complicated than it was. I used jezrael single line of code.