# how to find all matches in a string with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, list, file, findall

I have a string and I want to find all 13 digits numbers in it.
I wrote the code like this, but the problem is that I get a list which contains just the first 13 digits number.
Any one knows where's the problem.

my text:

*9311105005816 POTTING MIX OSMOCOTE PRO 501 PREMIUM 107899 4711414284189 BBQ ACC CLEANING SMALL GRILL BRUSH^ 9312566048022 SPRAY PAINT FIDDLY BITS 250G GREY PRIMER 9312324001115 GARDEN BASICS 25L ALL PURPOSE POTTING MIX 2 @ $3.50 8711167004368 FIRE IGNITION FIRELIGHTR SAMBA 36PK WHITE BRICK SAKF36 6 @*

my code:

```
import re

with open("Receipt.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

index_subtotal = lines[0].find("SubTotal")
index_tax_invoice = lines[0].find("TAX INVOICE 'Kip' ")
len_tax_invoice = len("TAX INVOICE 'Kip' ")

print(lines[0][index_tax_invoice + len_tax_invoice:index_subtotal])

print("*" * 30)

my_pattern = lines[0][index_tax_invoice + len_tax_invoice:index_subtotal]

my_pattern_list = re.findall("^(?:.*?(\d{10,13}).*|.*)$", my_pattern)

print(my_pattern_list)
```

Comment: Use `re.findall(r"\d{13}", text)`

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824942/regex-to-match-digits-of-specific-length)